# Call to a member function move() on null when update in laravel

Tags: laravel

I got this errror when trying to update data. If I update the image there's no error, but if I'm not it showing Call to a member function move() on null

This is my code:

```
public function update($id, Request $request)
{   
    $change = Profile::findorfail($id);
    $before = $change->foto_profil;
        
    $profile = [
        'fullname' => $request['fullname'],
        'phone' => $request['phone'],
        'ttl' => $request['ttl'],
        'foto_profil' => $before
    ];
    $request->foto_profil->move(public_path().'/image', $before);
    $change->update($profile);

    return redirect('/profil');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may determine if a file is present on the **request** using the `hasFile()` method :

```
if($request->hasFile('foto_profil')){
     $request->foto_profil->move(public_path().'/image', $before);
}
```

See the documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests#retrieving-uploaded-files)

Answer (score 1):

just add validation if photo exists in request

```
if($request->foto_profil) {
   $request->foto_profil->move(public_path().'/image', $before);
}
```